# How can I send messages to a Chrome extension from localhost?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, web-push, push-api

[Chrome apps are gone](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), so no [chrome.sockets.tcpServer](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer). [`chrome.gcm` is gone](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm), and Firebase is way too heavy for my interests (not that I ever used `chrome.gcm`). I just want to send messages from localhost; I don't want to register anything or maintain an app server. I tried the [Push API with Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user), but ran into problems.

What works:

- I can register a service worker. The registration eventually enters the active state.

What doesn't work:

- The `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` promise never resolves.
- `Notification.requestPermission` does nothing (but `Notification.permission === 'granted'` if I add the notification permission to the extension manifest).
- The `registration.pushManager.subscribe` promise never resolves.
- `registration.pushManager.permissionState` resolves to `'prompt'`, but no prompt ever appears.

None of this behavior fits [the documentation I linked](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?
Notify the user? or Communication between page and chrome extension? Or register a service worker via chrome extension?

Comment: I want to be able to trigger some action in the browser by sending a message over HTTP. I want the extension to listen, not to poll.

Comment: Since none of the behavior fits the documentation, you're probably doing something wrong and without a minimal example to reproduce the issue it is going to be hard to debug. You mention that the promise never resolves, but does it show or produce an error?